# Normalization of Thermal image with range 0 to 40

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, infrared

I'm doing research about using thermal image for temperature measurement for medical purposes, I try to repeat methodology of paper "Face and eyes localization algorithm in thermal images for temperature
measurement of the inner canthus of the eyes". They used Normalization of thermal image with range 0 to 40, and they got this results.

[image]

I tried the code below:

```
tt = imread('test.jpg');
figure, imshow(tt)
tt = double(tt);
normimg = uint8(zeros(size(tt))); 
for idx = 1 : 3
chan = tt(:,:,idx);
minvalue = min(chan(:));
maxvalue = max(chan(:));
normimg(:,:,idx) = uint8((chan-minvalue)*40/(maxvalue-minvalue)); 
end
figure, imshow(normimg)
```

and I got different results so what I should do to get same results 
Thank you in advance

[image]

Comment: Look at the colorbar on the second image. Look at the *display range* implied by the colorbar on the second image.

Comment: Is your Jpeg image grayscale? The way you open the image and display it makes me think is pseudo-colored.

Comment: to add to @nkjt . Try `imshow(normimg,[30 40])`

Answer (score 0):

You should first try to convert it to 2d matrix (Grayscale) then normalize it by the 40*(X-Min)/(Max-Min)

Comment: His code already does this. Check the 3rd line from the bottom.

Comment: I want normalize in rgb scale same as research paper did

Comment: Thank you @Meisam for your valuable reply, I tried your suggestion and I still get same results

Answer (score 0):

Your normalization is OK and the image is fine. The point is that "imshow" command assumes your image is in range [0~255] so if the maximum value of the image is 40, it will be dark in the figure. To see the image properly, put a "[]" in imshow command:

```
imshow(normimg,[])
```

And also you can do the whole job in just three lines:

```
tt = imread('test.jpg');
normimg = 40 * mat2gray(tt);
figure, imshow(normimg,[]);
```